# node-mocks-http ignoring res.end() call

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, next.js, jestjs, tdd

I am testing a login function in NextJS API routes. In my `login.ts` file, I search for the `targetUser` (user who is logging in) and if `targetUser` is null, then it means that the user does not exist and I run a `res.end(res.status(404).json("User does not exist"))` command. I used Insomnia (basically postman) and sent a mock request and the api route works as expected, but when I test it out, it fails.

login.ts

```
...imports

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const targetUser = await prisma.users.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
  
  //if targetUser (result of prisma.users.findUnique) is falsey, res.status is 404
  if(!targetUser) {
    res.end(res.status(404).json("User does not exist"))
  }

  if(!compareSync(req.body.password, targetUser!.password)) {
    res.end(res.status(404).json("User does not exist"))
  }

  res.end(res.status(200).json(targetUser))
}
```

login.test.ts

```
  ...imports
  
  //mocking "prisma.users.findUnique" used in login.ts
  jest.mock('../../prisma/client', () => {
    return {
      users: {
        findUnique: jest.fn(() => {return null}) //result of findUnique is falsey
      }
    }
  })

  const runHandler = async () => {
    const { req, res } = createMocks({
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        email: 'testmail@mail.com',
        password: 'testpassword'
      }
    })

    await handler(req, res)

    return { req, res }
  }

  test('Expect is user does not exist, give error', async () => {
    const {req, res} = await runHandler()
    expect(res._getStatusCode()).toBe(404)
  })
```